# Карусель на JS

Tags: jquery, slider, javascript, ui, плагин

Здравствуйте.

Посоветуйте карусель на JS (можно jQuery), которая удовлетворяет следующим требованиям:

- явная настройка адаптивности (в зависимости от ширины экрана показывает n элементов в полосе);
- настройка кнопок "влево" / "вправо" (назначить на уже существующие элементы страницы или  установить HTML в конфиг карусели);
- на полосе может быть n элементов;
- есть возможность перетаскивания полосы элементов (mouse drag);
- адаптировано для мобилок (touch drag / swipe);
- в элементах может быть сложная структура вложенных блоков (а не просто слайдер картинок);
- для вложенных блоков можно назначить jQuery.click.

Раньше использовал [kenwheeler/slick](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick), но у нее события click на вложенных элементах работают либо только на mobile (свойство mobileFirst:true), либо только на desktop (свойство mobileFirst:false), но не одновременно на обоих типах устройств.

Answer (score 1):

http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/ пойдет?
Не уверен насчет адаптировано для мобилок **(touch drag / swipe)**, но все остальное вроде есть.

Comment: В ней нет перетаскивания элементов полосы мышью (mouse drag)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com
Довольно неплохая 'Карусель Совы'.
Responsive + Touch & Swipe + Поддержка зомбо-браузеров.
Прост в применении и подключении.